# Set: Cannot Perform Set On Containers

Tags: ios, shell, info.plist, cfbundledisplayname

I am trying to update *CFBundleName* & *CFBundleDisplayName* in Info.plist using *PlistBuddy*

```
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set : CFBundleName test" info.plist
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set : CFBundleDisplayName test" info.plist
```

It works perfectly when the file is outside of the Xcode Project But when the file is inside the project It throws  "*Set: Cannot Perform Set On Containers*"

Why it happens and how about solving this without moving the file outside of the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Space between colon(:) and key name is the reason why it was throwing the error and now it works as expected

> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set **:CFBundleName test**" info.plist
>
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set **:CFBundleDisplayName tes**t" info.plist